# Create A New DataFrame Based on Conditions of Multiple DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I have two datasets: one with cancer positive patients (df_pos), and the other with the cancer negative patients (df_neg).

`df_pos`

```
    id
0   123
1   124
2   125
```

`df_neg`

```
    id
0   234
1   235
2   236
```

I want to compile these datasets into one with an extra column if the patient has cancer or not (yes or no).

Here is my desired outcome:

```
    id  outcome
0   123 yes
1   124 yes
2   125 yes
3   234 no
4   235 no
5   236 no
```

What would be a smarter approach to compile these?

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
>>> df_pos.assign(outcome='Yes').append(df_neg.assign(outcome='No'), ignore_index=True)
    id outcome
0  123     Yes
1  124     Yes
2  125     Yes
3  234      No
4  235      No
5  236      No
```

Comment: That's perfect, @Sayandip. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
df_pos['outcome'] = True
df_neg['outcome'] = False

df = pd.concat([df_pos, df_neg]).reset_index(drop=True)
```